# Spring error when loading view files

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat7

Hello I am developing a **spring-mvc** web application and having a strange error while Sprin controller loading view files.

Here is my controller:

```
package spring.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String list(Model md){
        return "student-list";
    }
}
```

Here is my student-list.jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Hello World</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally I would like to share my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.alinso</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
</dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.40</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5.2</version>
</dependency>



    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>



  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>hibernate</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <path>/</path>
                        <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
  </build>


</project>
```

Thanks in advance,,

EDIT:

Here is the error i get :

**HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/view/student_002dlist_jsp, and the class loader (instance of org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/realm/ClassRealm) for the method's defining class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have different Class objects for the type javax/el/ExpressionFactory used in the signature**

Comment: I think that it may be a good think that you share the error you are seeing

Comment: This is off topic until you edit to include the specific error you are seeing.

Comment: sorry, i forgot it,,

Comment: the error is added to question now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method  javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033065/java-lang-linkageerror-loader-constraint-violation-when-resolving-interface-me)

Comment: How is your [view resolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html) configuered